# need help to find dataset queries for the tables explained in SSRS tablix data region documentation

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

I have been going through the SSRS tablix data regions and grouping documentation; in the documentation, a table was shown that has 'Sales', 'Region', 'Year' and 'Sales Total' fields with row-groups and column-groups. I tried to find the relevant dataset (query) in the entire documentation relevant to this query and failed to find one. I am not yet good building joins to build the needed dataset.

Would anyone help in building or finding the dataset that is relevant to the table shown in the screenshot below; the table can also available in the web-link I included in this post.

[enter image description here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/tablix-data-region-areas-report-builder-and-ssrs?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: That is just explained how the tablix groups work. The data they use in the sample is probably just in a table or view that contains. `Continent, Country, Category, SubCategory, Year, SalesAmount` . That's it.  You should also mark answered as accepted if they resolved your issue. You seem to have a lot of questions answered with either no comments or not marked as answered.

Comment: Alan, Thanks for responding on my concern; for some examples mentioned in MS SSRS documentation, dataset query is  provided; however it looks there isn't dataset query given to the example I referred in the post.   You mentioned about accepting answer to know whether it is helpful; I am wandering if there is a button to accept-answer like other forums have. would you pls advise me on this? Thank you, Alan

Comment: When somebody posts an answer (not just a comment like this) then to left left are some buttons, there are the vote up/down buttons then below that a tick (check mark), this is the accept answer button. Watch the tour to see how the site works https://stackoverflow.com/tour